# Razor view Type does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webforms, webforms-view-engine, webforms-routing

I have a problem with configuring asp.net mvc application:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Type 'ASP._Page_Currency_Index_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage'.]
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp) +11454171
System.Web.WebPages.BuildManagerWrapper.CreateInstanceOfType(String virtualPath) +347
System.Web.WebPages.VirtualPathFactoryManager.CreateInstanceOfType(String virtualPath) +239
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.CreateFromVirtualPath(String virtualPath, IVirtualPathFactory virtualPathFactory) +57
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRoute.DoPostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context) +407
System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +270
```

Steps that I want to do:

- Move controllers with its views into separate library and put dll into bin folder.
- Create virtual file provider and virtual file to get data from assembly:

  ```
  public override Stream Open()
  {
      var resourceName = this.path;
      var asmName = this.assembly.GetName().Name;
      var manifestName = asmName + ".Views" + resourceName.Trim('~').Replace("/", ".");
      var resourceStream = this.assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(manifestName);
      return resourceStream;
  }
  ```
- Add this lines into web.config:

  ```
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
  ```
- When user access this controller's page it is compiled correctly into the following class:

  ```
  public class _Page_Currency_Index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<GridModel<CurrencyModel>> {
  ```
- And after that it fails with this error (and as I can see - he is right, Type 'ASP._Page_Currency_Index_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage'.)

What should I do to let HttpApplication know that this page should be managed as System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage instead of System.Web.WebPages.WebPage?

I have tried to move Views/Web.Config into bin folder, but it does not help.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding this to the `AppSettings` in `Web.Config`:

```
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
```