# ASP.Net MVC4 Root cshtml and "does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have followed the answers provided by very similar posts as you will see in the step by step listed below.

- [Razor view Type does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460913/razor-view-type-does-not-inherit-from-system-web-webpages-webpage)
- http://iamdotnetcrazy.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-solve-type-asppageviewstartcshtm.html

I still have the same error message "does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage'"

### Overview

I am learning from John Papa's "Single Page Apps with HTML5, Web API, Knockout and jQuery" on Pluralsight.  The course outlines building an application called "Code Camper".  The example MVC4 SPA creates a root view called "index.cshtml".  where a series of @RenderPage calls are made.  This application runs fine on my development machine. However, if i try to create from scratch a MVC4 SPA with a root view.cshtml I always get the error "does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage"

### Step by Step

Download [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=EDAFB4DBECFEE2EA!4849&authkey=!ACSorle8q0hebwY).

1.Create a new MVC4 Internet Project called "MVC4RootView"

2.In the root of the project, create a RootView.cshtml view.

```
@{
Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
            @RenderPage("Views/Partial1.cshtml")
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

3.Added a “~/Views/Partial1.cshtml” with just a simple div

```
<div>Hello from Partial 1</div>
```

4.Modified root Web.Config webpages:Enabled to true.

```
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
```

5.Added system.web.webPages.razor to root Web.config

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

6.Added sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" to configSections of root web.config

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor"
    type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup,
    System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
    PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">       
    <section name="host"
        type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection,
        System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
        PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="pages"
        type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection,
        System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
        PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
```

7.Set RootView.cshtml as Start Page

8.Run and get the following error:  "Type 'ASP._Page_RootView_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage'.

I am at a loss of how to fix this.  The Code Camper code works fine.  I have compared line by line and see no differences in the code that would prevent from working.

Thoughts?
Dan

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Remove the `web.config` from your `Views` folder.

As you're including `Partial1.cshtml` from that folder, it is also including the web.config from within there.  And that web.config is saying that all pages must inherit from WebViewPage.

Comment: I did as you suggested and i still get the same error.  All i have in my "View" folder now is the PartialView1.cshtml.  I uploaded my changes here.  https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=EDAFB4DBECFEE2EA!8040&authkey=!ANxu2W1IPxOBsOE

Comment: Oh... try to also remove the sections you added to your root web.config in your points 5. and 6.

Comment: Works now.  Awesome and much appreciated!!

Comment: This rendered all my views rife with syntax errors. This file is apparently crucial.

Answer (score 3):

I am a beginner to this, but one thing I did not realise is that cshtml pages are served through a controller, rather than by loading them directly.

In combination with the above, I also had to set the following key to false in the web.config file:

```
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
```

Comment: Yep, this solved the issue for me. I wasn't using any C# in my view, so I changed it to a plain HTML file and now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Do not delete the webconfig, is a very important file in your views!!!

Instead, do this:

Enable "View all Files" in the web project that is failing, and search for a file that seems correct but is not included in visual studio, and delete it. If it fails in your deployment folder, try to clean the folder as well, and re-deploy the site, you might have unnecesary files that might cause the same problem.

In my case, at the root of the webproject I had an extra copy of _ViewStart.cshtml (excluded from the project), I deleted that file, and that did the trick.

Hope it helps, let me know if this solve your problem as well.

Comment: Deleting the `_ViewStart.cshtml` resolved the issue for me. Thanks @Yogurtu