# 'ASP._Page_sitecore_shell_client_Speak_Layouts_Layouts_Speak_Layout_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.1

When we try to browse images in sitecore 7.1 application are getting the below error which is migrated from 6.2 to 7.1.

> Type
>   'ASP._Page_sitecore_shell_client_Speak_Layouts_Layouts_Speak_Layout_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage

Comment: Can you check if you enabled Mvc on your Sitecore 7.1 solution ?

Comment: Also take a look at the web.config in your views folder. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402315/asp-net-mvc4-root-cshtml-and-does-not-inherit-from-system-web-webpages-webpage for more information

Answer (score 10):

What you need to do is either:

- Go to your `App_Config/Include` folder, and rename `Sitecore.MVC.config.disabled` to `Sitecore.MVC.config`;
- Or disable SPEAK (by renaming the SPEAK configs).

Comment: this should have the answer flag. Thx!

Comment: We were running into this issue, as well, with our recent 7.1 upgrade (from 6.4), and we are not using MVC yet. Looks like enabling the Sitecore.MVC.config file has addressed the error, but should we expect any unintended result from enabling the MVC config if we're not yet using MVC?

Comment: No, as far as I've found it all works fine. I don't have any MVC in my solution either and haven't found any issues yet

Comment: Thanks, @Trayek, I opened a Sitecore support ticket after running into a weird issue with the SPEAK interface for media selection, and asked about MVC. Their answer confirmed it:

"Starting from Sitecore 7.1, the MVC is enabled by default. It should not cause any issues even if you do not use it.
The issue is that the MVC config is disabled after the upgrade. This is caused by the problem with the upgrade package. It doesn’t install this config properly....However in a clean Sitecore 7.1 the MVC configs is enabled."