# 7.1 Images field not able to open "getting ystem.Web.WebPages.WebPage error"

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.1

I got the following error while opening images in Sitecore 7.1 which got migrated from 6.2 to 7.1:

```
Type 'ASP._Page_sitecore_shell_client_Speak_Layouts_Layouts_Speak_Layout_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage'.
```

Can someone please help how to overcome this?

Comment: Can you check if you enabled MVC for Sitecore 7.1 ?

Answer (score 4):

I think I found solution for your problem. 
Please enabled from **Website\App_Config\Include** folder Sitecore.Mvc.config file .

I can replicate your error.

If I disabled it it throw me same error like on your side. 
Please check attached picture .

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore 7.1 REQUIRES mvc to be active for SPEAK interfaces, like the image editor in your case. If you do not want MVC active, you should disable SPEAK as well..

Answer (score 0):

Same question here: ['ASP._Page_sitecore_shell_client_Speak_Layouts_Layouts_Speak_Layout_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471147/asp-page-sitecore-shell-client-speak-layouts-layouts-speak-layout-cshtml-does). We ran into this problem, too, after upgrading from 6.4 to 7.1, and just had to enable the Sitecore.Mvc.config file -- Sitecore confirmed there's no harm in doing that, even if you're not using MVC, and that, in clean 7.1 installs, MVC is enabled by default.