# New MVC Area _layout does not inherit....System.Web.WebPages.StartPage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a basic MVC project and I added an area to it for admin type functionality called.....Admin.

Then because I want my admin area somewhat autonomous from the rest of the site as there will be assemblies, functionality etc. for the admin the user's don't need.

I then added a _ViewStart.cshtml to the root of the Admin area.

```
@{
   Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Of course then I added _Layout.cshtml in the Admin/Views/Shared folder.

Loading the public site is fine loading the admin area:

> 'ASP._Page_Areas_Admin__ViewStart_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.StartPage'

Googling I find numerous people who have opted to have the main site _Layout serve their areas as well.

This is the reverse of what I want...but I could be wrong in my thinking?

I read this post as well:

[ASP.Net MVC4 Root cshtml and "does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402315/asp-net-mvc4-root-cshtml-and-does-not-inherit-from-system-web-webpages-webpage)

and have added a web.config that is an exact copy of the main branch view folder to the Admin/Views folder to no avail.

So am I violating some practice by having a _Layout for the Admin area?

If not then what am I missing..I mean I understand the error but thought adding the web.config with the assemblies would add the namespaces needed?

Answer (score 4):

I just had this issues as well. The error was down to the fact that I had put the **_ViewStart.cshtml** file in the area root folder of the area instead of **Areas > [Area Name] > Views** folder. Once you move it to the **Areas> [Area Name] > Views** folder all should work as expected, as long as everything else is configured correctly.

Comment: Information of the day! I don't know how I missed that. Thanks!